# No input file specified codeigniter

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter

I made a website on codeigniter which works fine on one server. But when I upload the same website on another server, it displays **No input file specified** error. Everything, **even the .htaccess file is same on both servers**.

Here's the .htaccess im using :

```
<IfModule authz_core_module>
Require all denied
</IfModule>
<IfModule !authz_core_module>
    Deny from all
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|public|\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?$1
```

**This works** : (http://www.mridulahuja.com/api/index.php/leads?user=username&pass=userpassword)

**But this does not** : (http://www.mridulahuja.com/api/leads?user=username&pass=userpassword)

**Repeat** : The exact same .htaccess is working perfectly on my other server 
www.kudammcorp.com/gsm100ad/api/leads?user=username&pass=userpassword

(can't post the last url as a link due to low reputation pts.)

Comment: Check the file permission.

Comment: all folders have permission : 0755

Comment: Try with `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1` or with `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Tpojka, it but sill doesn't work.

Comment: your htaccess is not working on your new server. Check if rewrite is enable on your server or not/